# Flutter Bloc re-emitting previous state automatically

Tags: flutter, bloc, state-management, flutter-bloc

**I wanted to make a timer based on the Internet cubit. when Internet Disconnected State is emitted timer should be reset. But after reset(when Internet Disconnect state emitted) it is emitting increment timer state again.**

***Home Cubit (timer cubit)***

```
class HomeCubit extends Cubit<HomeState> {
  HomeCubit() : super(HomeState.initial());

  void increment() {
    Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
      emit(state.copyWith(counter: state.counter + 1));
    });
  }

  void reset() {
    emit(
      state.copyWith(counter: 0),
    );
  }
}
```

***Home State (timer state)***

```
class HomeState extends Equatable {
  final int counter;
  const HomeState({
    required this.counter,
  });

  factory HomeState.initial() {
    return const HomeState(counter: 0);
  }

  HomeState copyWith({
    int? counter,
  }) {
    return HomeState(
      counter: counter ?? this.counter,
    );
  }

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [counter];
}
```

***Internet Cubit***

```
class InternetCubit extends Cubit<InternetState> {
  final Connectivity connectivity;
  late StreamSubscription internetStreamSubscription;

  InternetCubit({required this.connectivity}) : super(InternetInitial()) {
    monitorInternet();
  }

  void monitorInternet() {
    internetStreamSubscription = connectivity.onConnectivityChanged.listen((connectivityResult) {
      if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.wifi) {
        emit(const InternetConnected(connectionType: ConnectionType.wifi));
      } else if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.mobile) {
        emit(const InternetConnected(connectionType: ConnectionType.mobileData));
      } else if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.none) {
        emit(InternetDisconnected());
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Future<void> close() {
    internetStreamSubscription.cancel();
    return super.close();
  }
}
```

***Internet State***

```
enum ConnectionType { wifi, mobileData }

abstract class InternetState extends Equatable {
  const InternetState();

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class InternetInitial extends InternetState {}

class InternetConnected extends InternetState {
  final ConnectionType connectionType;

  const InternetConnected({required this.connectionType});
  @override
  List<Object> get props => [connectionType];
}

class InternetDisconnected extends InternetState {}
```

***Homepage view***

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocListener<InternetCubit, InternetState>(
      listener: (context, state) {
        if (state is InternetConnected) {
          context.read<HomeCubit>().increment();
        } else if (state is InternetDisconnected) {
          context.read<HomeCubit>().reset();
        }
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              const Text('You have been connected to the Internet for the past'),
              Text(context.watch<HomeCubit>().state.counter.toString()),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**I tried Cubit stream subscribe too. but why it is re-emitting old state again? why timer not staying in 0 or reset state?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want the timer to stay 0 when you call `reset()` in HomeCubit().

Try this:

```
class HomeCubit extends Cubit<HomeState> {
  HomeCubit() : super(HomeState.initial());
  Timer? timer;

  void increment() {
    timer ??= Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
      emit(state.copyWith(counter: state.counter + 1));
    });
  }

  void reset() {
    timer?.cancel();
    timer = null;
    emit(
      state.copyWith(counter: 0),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: it solved the problem but it won't emit increment again when the internet is turned on again I mean it totally canceled the timer but I want the timer will continue incrementing from zero when the internet is reconnected again.

**[ I solved this new problem with just removing timer ??= to timer = ... ]**

Comment: I edited my answer. It should work now.